# BigQuerty - “Row larger than the maximum allowed size” for a 10MB JSON

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm getting an error "Row larger than the maximum allowed size" although the row size (JSON) is 9750629 bytes (less than 10MB).

Documentation states that the limit is 20MB for JSON.

Erroneous job is job_3QR3cLzoTDX5m_2T8OgdVHdvlBs

Answer (score 0):

I checked with the engineering team, and the actual limit is 2MB. Thanks for reporting this - the documentation has been updated accordingly.

I'm still interested in having the actual limit being 20MB. Any additional information will help me make a better case. Thanks!

Comment: I'm using BQ to save data that originated in XML report: this data has multiple nesting level and many repeated elements, and can possibly (although not very frequently) be over 1MB. I can understand that for a (relational) DB record to be so large doesn't make sense, but a BQ table maps to multiple DB records (via repeated elements), so it does make sense one record loaded to BQ may be several MBs. HTH :)